# jQuery Span Text not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

My problem is that if I execute this code in the browser console, it is working properly, the spans get changed according to the URL parameter given etc. But if I just load the page, I get the respective console logs but no spans are filled. Does anybody see a problem?

P.S. Window on load was a desperation move so don't judge me, it's optional.

EDIT: I should maybe mention that I come from Python programming so I might not understand certain things to do with JS... sry

jQuery Code:

```
function setSlogan(sloganText) {
   console.log(sloganText);
   $("#productLeadLogin").text(sloganText);
   $("#productLeadRegistration").text(sloganText);
}



const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

function chooseSlogan (){
    switch (params.get("product")) {
        case "...":
            console.log("Got ...");
            slogan = "to the ... services";
            console.log(slogan);
            setSlogan(slogan);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("defaulting");
            slogan = "to all your default services";
            console.log(slogan);
            setSlogan(slogan);
            break;
    }
}

$(window).on("load", chooseSlogan()); // it's called desperation
```

one of the spans to change:

```
<h6 class="font-weight-light">Sign In here to get access <span id="productLeadLogin"></span>.</h6>
```

Comment: You need to pass the _reference_ to your function object as callback parameter in `.on`, but you are _calling_ it directly in that place. Difference `foo()`  vs `foo`

Comment: Should be: `$(window).on("load", chooseSlogan);`

Comment: @freedomn-m could you please post this as an answer so I can accept it? *Passing the function on load works!* Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $(window).on("load", chooseSlogan());
> ```

You need to pass the *reference* to your function object as callback parameter in `.on`, but you are *calling*  it directly in that place. Difference `foo()` vs `foo`.

So this part needs to be

```
 $(window).on("load", chooseSlogan);
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! As I may mention this also works with `$(document).ready(foo);`